# getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(RecipientPublicAddress) always give Error: Failed to find account

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, solana

const senderPublicKey = new PublicKey("sender public wallet address in string");

const recipientPublicKey = new PublicKey("recipient public wallet address in string");

const mint = new PublicKey("token mint address in string");

const token = new Token(
connection,
mint,
TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
senderPublicKey
);

const senderTokenAccount = await token.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(senderPublicKey);

const recipientTokenAccount = await token.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(recipientPublicKey);

The getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo works only after I manually pass spl-Token/nft to the recipient wallet address. Before passing it shows ERROR: Failed to find account.

Cannot figure out what will be the problem and solution. I even tried createAssociatedTokenAccount() too yet got some string related issue.